# How to predict Y using PLS-Canonical model given the X matrix?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, partial-least-squares

Recently I've been learning Partial Least Squares (PLS), and learned that there are some variations of PLS, namely PLS-Canonical, PLS-SVD, PLS2 and PLS1 (mainly from the [User Guide of PLS classes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_decomposition.html#cross-decompositionhttps://) in the python's scikit-learn library. I could understand most of it, and have read the reference that page has provided ([A survey of Partial Least Squares (PLS) methods, with emphasis on the two-block case, by JA Wegelin](https://stat.uw.edu/sites/default/files/files/reports/2000/tr371.pdf). Nevertheless, I still have questions about the details of predicting $Y$ based on new samples.

For example, assume we have two matrix blocks $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$, and I want to formulate a regression model based on PLS-Canonical. In PLS-Canonical, we first calculate the first first pair of latent scores of $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$, using the first pair of left and right singular vectors of $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y}$ associated with the largest singular value, $\boldsymbol{u}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{v}_1$. The calculated latent scores would be $\boldsymbol{\xi}_1 = \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{u}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}_1 = \mathbf{Y} \boldsymbol{v}_1$; the rest pairs of $\boldsymbol{\xi}_r$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}_r$ where $r > 1$ would be calculated using the same approach based on $\mathbf{X}^{(r)}$ and $\mathbf{Y}^{(r)}$, where $\mathbf{X}^{(r)}$ is the residual after the deflation of $\mathbf{X}^{(r-1)}$ based on $\boldsymbol{\xi}_{r-1}$, and $\mathbf{Y}^{(r)}$ is obtained similarly, and $\mathbf{X}^{(1)} = \mathbf{X}$, $\mathbf{Y}^{(1)} = \mathbf{Y}$.

No problems so far, but how to regress $\mathbf{Y}$ on $\mathbf{X}$? Based on my understanding (or my guess), we do a one-to-one regression of each of the pairs
$$
\hat{\boldsymbol{\omega}}_r = \frac{\boldsymbol{\xi}_r \boldsymbol{\xi}_r^T \boldsymbol{\omega}_r }{\boldsymbol{\xi}_r^T \boldsymbol{\xi}_r} = \alpha_r \boldsymbol{\xi}_r,
$$
and then
$$
\hat{\mathbf{Y}} = \sum_{r=1}^R  \alpha_r \boldsymbol{\xi}_r \boldsymbol{\delta}_r^T,
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\delta}_r$ is the loading of $\boldsymbol{\omega}_r$. In matrix form, it would be
$$
\hat{\mathbf{Y}} = \mathbf{\Xi} 
\left[ \begin{matrix}
\alpha_1 & & \\
& \ddots & \\
& & \alpha_R
\end{matrix} \right]
 \mathbf{\Delta}^T.
$$

I thought I had been correct until I saw [the source code of scikit-learn's implementation of PLS-Canonical](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/364c77e04/sklearn/cross_decomposition/_pls.py#L667). In the `predict` method, it appears that

```py
Ypred = X @ self._coef_.T
```

and `self._coef_` is computed as follows:

```py
# here self.x_rotations_ is a transformation matrix such that X @ self.x_rotations_ would be Xi.
self._coef_ = np.dot(self.x_rotations_, self.y_loadings_.T)
self._coef_ = (self._coef_ * self._y_std).T
```

which seems to be
$$
\hat{\mathbf{Y}} = \mathbf{\Xi} \mathbf{\Delta}^T,
$$
where no involvement of $\alpha_r$'s is found.

I expect scikit-learn to be correct, so I am confused by the difference between my understanding and the implementation of sklearn. Have I got anything wrong? Any help would be appreciated!